# Prove by mathematical induction that $1^3+2^3+...n^3=1/4(n^2(n+1)^2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

In my attempt I arrived at $1/4(k^2(k+1)^2+4(k+1)^3)$ and don't know how to make any progress from there. I'm supposed to go from there to $(1/4(k+1)^2(k+2)^2)$ but have no idea how.

Comment: I do not see where the 4 of at 4(k+1)^3 comes from. It seems wrong. Anyways, I would try to factor out (k+1) at that point.

Comment: A good way to use induction to prove that two sequences coincide, especially when one of them is written as a sum,  is to show that $a_1=b_1$ and then to show that $a_n-a_{n-1}=b_n-b_{n-1}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Factor $(k+1)^2$ out of $k^2(k+1)^2+4(k+1)^3$.

You will find that it is $(k+1)^2(k^2+4k+4)$ which further simplifies to $(k+1)^2(k+2)^2$